# InviteRedirectURL not working for AAD guest user invite

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure Active Directory and a SPA App registration.

I am using the Microsoft Graph endpoint to invite a Guest User to the AD.

**Graph Invite Api**

**Doc followed** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

**request URL** - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations (POST request)

**request BODY** -

```
{
    invitedUserDisplayName: "John Doe", 
    invitedUserEmailAddress: "johndoe@org.com",
    inviteRedirectUrl: "https://example.com",
    "sendInvitationMessage": true,
    "invitedUserMessageInfo": {
      "customizedMessageBody": ""
    }
 }
```

This sends an AAD invitation at **invitedUserEmailAddress** and a redemption link in the mail.
(This also adds a guest user entry to the list of users in my AAD with invitation status as pending acceptance)

Now if the user clicks on the redemption link in their mail,
they are successfully redirected to **inviteRedirectUrl**
(Invitation status for the user changes from pending acceptance to Accepted in AAD)

**My problem** -
But if a user tries to SignIn directly to https://portal.azure.com or my SPA (without/before accepting the invitation sent to their Email)
they are prompted "Review Permissions" page for getting added to AAD but after that
they are not redirected to **inviteRedirectUrl**.

I am tracking the status of the user's invitation status using **inviteRedirectUrl** (changing the invite status when **inviteRedirectUrl** is called),
which I am unable to do if the user directly tries to SignIn to my SPA.

Is this the desired behavior to not call **inviteRedirectUrl** if someone tries to sign in directly or can this be remediated somehow?

Comment: I've also noticed the behaviour is different for accessing an app in the target tenant directly vs clicking the invite accept link. If the user is not an AAD/personal MS account, they actually can't accept the invite by going directly to the app, only through the link. This may be something you can't affect. You can also track invitation approval by querying for the user through Graph API / setting up change notifications etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behavior is normal and as juunas mentioned in comments, you can use graph api to query the user and know the invitation approval status.

You can request the graph api like: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}?$select=externalUserState`. The field `externalUserState` shows the status of invitation approval status.

Comment: thanks, I checked the graph API and it works well. That being said, I think the invite redeem endpoint having different behavior for redirectUri doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hello @AbhishekSharma, When you say that the users directly try to access this SPA prior to they being added as guest users in your tenant, still they are able to access the app, but this I have one question, is this SPA registered in AAD as a Multi-tenant app? If yes then the second question would be, this user, is this a user with Microsoft account (live.com account) or its a user or another AAD tenant? Why I ask this is because, if the user is from another AAD tenant and if the SPA is a multi-tenant app, this is an expected behavior.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, As in this case, when the user tries to access the multi-tenant SPA, the SPA is getting registered in their own AAD tenant after the user provides the consents to the "Review Permissions" page. In this case, even if the user is not added to your domain as Guest User, still he/she would be able to access your app, if the app is a multi-tenant app

Comment: @SouravMishra-MSFT I did not understand the part where you said _"even if the user is not added to your domain as Guest User, still he/she would be able to access your app"._ For them to be able to access my AD app, they'd need to be invited to AD first regardless of the app is multi-tenant or not right? 

Once they approve the Consent/accept invite they are automatically added to my AD and that is why they are able to access the app is what I understand.

Comment: @SouravMishra-MSFT anyway my main concern was about **redirectUri** parameter of /invitations graph API, which doesn't work if the redemption link is not clicked and the user tries to sign in to any Microsoft resource directly, either Azure portal or SPA.

I now understand that  **redirectUri** will only work thru redemption link and not otherwise.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, yes regarding RedirectURI your understanding is correct. The redirectURI is basically the URI where the IDP needs to redirect the user back after the auth successfully completes.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, regarding the previous comment, what I meant is, lets say user 1 is a part of an AAD Tenant called Tenant A and you hold a tenant called Tenant B, where your SPA resides. Now if user1 tries to access your SPA and if your SPA is configured as a multi-tenant app, then user1 will be able to access that app easily and once provided the consent by user1, the SPA's service principal object would get registered in user1's tenant i.e tenant A. In that way the can still access your app by not being added as a guest user in your tenant i,e tenant B.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, Now if you want user1 of Tenant A, should only be able to access your SPA when he/she is a part of your Tenant, i.e Tenant B, in that case, first thing would be make your SPA a Single Tenant App, and then get user1 added to your tenant as a guest user, by sending him and invitation. Once User1 gets added to your Tenant B as a guest user, he can access the Single Tenant SPA app, provided you have give permission for Guest users to access the app in your tenant.

Comment: @SouravMishra-MSFT My SPA is indeed a Multitenant.
**(Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**
And this is the behavior when a user who is not part of my tenant tries to sign in to SPA.
**AADSTS50020:** User account 'sample@user.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'My Tenant' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'(My SPA) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, Yes, though your SPA is a multi-tenant app, but by selecting the option of "Accounts in any organizational directory", you make sure that the user who is trying to access your SPA app, is a part of some AAD tenant as I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, But looking into the error it says "User account 'sample@user.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'My Tenant' " it getting thrown since you have created a user of multi-tenant app type Accounts in any organizational directory, but then you are trying to login with a user of may be outlook.com or hotmail.com who are part of live.com accounts. To support users from live.com for your Multi-tenant apps, you can select "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox):

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, select that option would get you the same experience of a user in live account can also access your multi-tenant SPA without being a part of your Tenant. But surely with you multi-tenant app type as "Accounts in any organizational directory", you certainly need the live.com user to be added as a guest user to your tenant or some other AAD tenant to access your SPA.

Comment: @SouravMishra-MSFT ohh ohk I got your point. So a user from Other ADs would still be able to consent and access to my AD app even if they are not invited as a Guest User.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, correct, since your SPA is registered as a Multitenant app with "Accounts in any organization directory" selected. Please accept the below response as answer if this helped you in clearing your doubts. If any further queries around this, please feel free to reach out to us.

Answer (score 1):

The SPA is a multi-tenant app, but by selecting the option of "Accounts in any organizational directory", you make sure that the user who is trying to access your SPA app, is a part of some AAD tenant as I mentioned in my earlier comment.

But looking into the error it says "User account 'sample@user.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'My Tenant' " it getting thrown since you have created a user of multi-tenant app type Accounts in any organizational directory, but then you are trying to login with a user of may be outlook.com or hotmail.com who are part of live.com accounts. To support users from live.com for your Multi-tenant apps, you can select "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox):

select that option would get you the same experience of a user in live account can also access your multi-tenant SPA without being a part of your Tenant. But surely with you multi-tenant app type as "Accounts in any organizational directory", you certainly need the live.com user to be added as a guest user to your tenant or some other AAD tenant to access your SPA.